# node.js express router.post gives 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have a quite simple node.js application that shall control some leds via a REST interface. There are pages that shall display certain infos - those are created from pug templates. And some other REST endpoints shall turn on or off an led.

My problem is that I can return an html site with **get**, but I can't execute a function via a **post**.

This is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var led = require('../public/javascripts/driveredled');

/* GET Red LED page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('oneled', { title: 'Red LED' });
});

// base path is already set as being /leds/{color}
router.post('/on', function(req, res) {
  led.turnledon();
});

// base path is already set as being /leds/{color}
router.post('/off', function(req, res) {
  led.turnledoff();
});

// base path is already set as being /leds/{color}
router.post('/blink', function(req, res) {
  led.blinkled();
});

module.exports = router;
```

and here is the log output:

```
sudo npm start
> ledconodel@0.1.0 start /data/shared/Developing/ledconodel
> node ./bin/www

Listening on port port 3000
GET /leds/blue/ 200 2291.133 ms - -
GET /leds/blue/ 304 229.306 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 11.105 ms - -
GET /leds/blue/on 404 328.030 ms - 1155
```

As can be seen, the html page (dynamically created via pug) is returned correctly, but the post command to the endpoint **on**, is not.

I'm very new to node.js, express and associated concepts, so I'm rather stuck here.

Can anyone help?

Kind regards,

Chris

Comment: As can be seen from your output, you seem to be making a GET request to `/on` instead of a POST request.

Comment: It's because you are trying to access your endpoint with GET and not with POST.

Comment: That's because you're not returning anything when a post request is made. do something like  `router.post('/on', function(req, res) {
  led.turnledon();
  res.json({ status: 'success' });
});
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GET /leds/blue/on 404 328.030 ms - 1155
```

From the log output, it seems you are invoking GET, not POST. And since you have not exposed GET on /on context, you are getting 404.

Can you please post as to how you are invoking your service.

Comment: Hi and thanks to your reply. I changed the code from post to get, but now I get a 500 error like this:  GET /leds/red/on 500 104.539 ms - 1250
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 1.881 ms - -
GET /leds/red/on 500 88.065 ms - 1250
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 18.859 ms - -

Answer (score 1):

When you try to access a specific route eg. `/on`, your browser by default uses `GET`method to route.. so you will get a `404` error

use some other software like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to simulate a `POST` method [as shown in this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehj3a.png)

Comment: Thank you very much. As I only try to turn the led on and off, I decided to change the command from post to get. But now I'm greeted with a 500 error :-(

Comment: 500 means an "Internal Server Error" there may be an issue with your code so to check whether ur route works .. add a `console.log("Testing");` inside your callback.. and test it.

Comment: perfectly well now on my site :-) Everything works as expected. I had an issue with the function (to turn on the led) not being exported that caused the 500